# Is there method to print out names of functions in a file in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Does Visual Studio 2015 Community edition have a method to *print out* names of functions in a file. I have a program of 3000 lines of code and want to put related functions into seperate header files. I want to make sure that the header and its related .cpp file has same functions.

I don't want to end up putting functions in wrong header or source file and am trying to think the best way to do this.

Comment: Have you considered writing a simple script with Python or any other scripting language to do that for you? That's much simpler than doing it from C++.

Comment: well, I don't know python. The main program is in C++. I am trying to disect it and put into seperate files. I am electronic engineer by the way, don't usually deal with high level programming language.

Comment: Learning Python will cost you one afternoon. Python is a joke compared to C++ (or pick any other scripting language of your choice). On the other hand, you *should* be knowing a high-level scripting language. Doing everything in C++ is a BIG waste of time. If you want to save time, the way is to use the right tool for the job. You can use CMake, for example, to run the script every time you build and raise flags. Of course, what I'm saying is suggestions. This is how I would do it. Do what fits you :)